# Of what help is SE linux to me?

Tags: security, selinux

i am new to Linux. I have heard about SE linux ... how does it work with Ubuntu and what can i do with it?

Comment: Ubuntu uses apparmor not selinux

Comment: @EdiD, by default sure, but you can switch if you want so the question is perfectly valid.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELinux is a security extension focused on restricting access to files based on the program being run rather than the user running it.  For example, your web browser does not need access to every file that your account has access to, so SELinux can be configured to ony give it access to the files it needs, so that even if you go to a bad web site that takes over your browser and tries to access your files, the access will be denied.

AppArmor is a similar ( though simpler ) system that Ubuntu uses by default.